# Question about taboo probability in Markov Chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

**Question**:
Assume that the state space of Markov Chain $S=\mathbb{N}$, and if state $i$ is recurrent, then prove
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{lim}_{N\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_k\neq i \ \mathrm{for\ all\ integers}\ k\in[n+1,n+N]|X_0=i)=0 
\end{align*}
where $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$

Here is what I thought:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X_k\neq i \ \mathrm{for\ all\ integers}\ k\in[n+1,n+N]|X_0=i)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}P_{ij}^{(n)}\sum_{l=N+1}^{\infty}f_{ji,n}^{(l)}
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
f_{ji,n}^{(l)}=\mathbb{P}(X_{n+l}=i,X_m\neq i,m\in[N+1,N+l]|X_{n}=j)
\end{align*}
and my question is whether the $f_{ji,n}^{(l)}$ is equal to $f_{ji,0}^{(l)}$.

If the above statement is true, then I want to prove the remainder $\sum_{l=N+1}^{\infty}f_{ji,n}^{l}$ goes to $0$, when $N\rightarrow\infty$.

So, I think about whether or not the state $j$ is recurrent, if it's true then I can apply the theorem which is $\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}f_{ji}^{(l)}=1$, then the remainder will become zero, when $N\rightarrow\infty$. However, what if the state $j$ is not recurrent, how should I prove?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this more simply. Let $\tau$ denote the hitting time of $i$ after at least $n$ steps. Then, $\Pr_i(\tau < \infty) = 1$ because $i$ is recurrent. Indeed, wherever $X$ is after $n$ steps, it will definition return.

So, given $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $N_\varepsilon > 0$ such that $\Pr_i(\tau \le N_\varepsilon) \ge 1 - \varepsilon$. But, this exactly says that your long probability is at least $1 - \varepsilon$ for $N \ge N_\varepsilon$. Since $\varepsilon > 0$ was arbitrary, this proves that the limit is $0$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but how can I strictly prove $\mathbb{P}(\tau<\infty)=1$? Does this formula mean $\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}f_{ii}^{k}=1$?

Comment: @BongseoChoi The definition of recurrent is that $\mathbb P_j(\tau_i < \infty) = 1$ for all $i,j \in S$. Here, $\tau_i$ is the hitting time of $i$ and $\mathbb P_j$ indicates that you start from $j$. For general $n \ge 0$, you don't start from a specific $j$, but from some distribution, say $\lambda$, on $S$. But, then
$$\textstyle \mathbb P_\lambda(\tau_i < \infty) = \sum_j \mathbb P_j(\tau_i < \infty) \mathbb P_\lambda(X_0 = j) = 1,$$
since every probability $\mathbb P_j(\tau_i < \infty) = 1$ and $\sum_j \mathbb P_\lambda(X_0 = j) = 1$

Comment: @BongseoChoi Does this answer your question? If so, you should hit the Accept tick mark ✔, that will move it out of the "answered" section to the "answered" section :)

Comment: Sorry to reply late, since I forgot to check the message.